# The best way to comment code in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, comments, enterprise

What's the best way to comment code in Java, is there a way to generate the function name and the parameters automatically in Eclipse ?

For example I'm writting those comments manually :

```
// <summary>
// Some comments about the function
// </summary>
// <param name="id">the user ID</param>
// <param name="username">The user password</param>
// <returns></returns>
public Connect(int id, String password)
{

}
```

Thanks already.

Comment: in eclipse, before the method, type:  /** and press enter

Comment: Use javadoc for this.  This allows for automatically generating documentation, which is nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally prefer to use [JAutodoc](http://jautodoc.sourceforge.net/index.html#download) plugin for commenting. Take a look at it. Its good.

Comment: Yes, but auto-generated javadoc comments are useless.  It is better to use `CTRL+ALT+J` to add the comment skeletons ... and then immediately add the actual comment.

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at [Javadoc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html)

Javadocs can easily be generated in Eclipse.  You can type `/**` and it will autocomplete.  You can also configure your code templates to automatically generate javadocs.

Comment: I'm talking about writing code in the source file, and not generating java doc sir.

Comment: Edited the answer. Changed the link, didn't mean to link to the generator tool but to javadoc documentation in general.

Answer (score 7):

Select the method for which you want comments and press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd> and <kbd>J</kbd> together.

Take the time to learn about JavaDoc as well it's a very rich area for documenting your code.

Answer (score 4):

By convention this is the way to do it:

```
/** Some comments about the function
  * 
  * @param id the user ID
  * @param username The user password
  *
*/
public Connect(int id, String password)
{

}
```

If your method returns anything, you would add a `@return' followed by an explanation.

You IDE and the standard JavaDoc tool will be able to parse this.

Comment: what a bad example, your first line is not formatted, you don't end the comments with ".", you once start with lower case, then you start with UPPERCASE

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some confusion on this thread.  The key sequence I use to generate javadoc comments is <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> not <kbd>CTRL</kbd>?

Comment: I also use SHIFT and not CTRL. I don't know why others are recommending the combination with CTRL.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use Javadoc comment format, not the one you shown in the question.

In Eclipse, put your cursor on the method name and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. It will generate you a Javadoc comment with all parameters listed.

You can also control the way Javadoc comment is generated in Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates -> Comments

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use JavaDoc and eclipse has built in code templates for doing just that.

If you want to have the format you've shown here, then you can write your own templates.  The templates functionality will allow you to insert variables, of which one will be the method name.

Answer (score 1):

You need to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> in same time having the cursor on the declaration row.

Comment: Please don't link to LMGT or suggest to other users RTFM, it's just plain rude and not constructive. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that the best way to comment code in java is to provide meaningful names for your methods and variables names :)

```
class MyService {
    public void authenticateUser(int userId, String userPassword) {...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go with the shift+alt+j for Eclipse, and write the description of the function so that other developer can understand what the function can do and also this auto commenting functionality will provide the @param and @return attributes so that you can specify what should be needed and what should be expected in order to execute the function.

For Example:

```
/**
 * @param msg
 * will return the converted message from the byte[] msg
 * @return
 */
```